# Change the color of options and show different widgets by taping on them in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I am using flutter. I want to change the color of a particular option when I tap on it, not all the options at the same time. When we press an option its color changes and it shows different widgets below it(like tab bar). The code is attached below. I am glad if someone helps. ..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class cards extends StatelessWidget {
const cards({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("Cards"),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        optionCards("A", "assets/icons/recycle.png", context),
        optionCards("B", "assets/icons/tools.png", context),
        optionCards("C", "assets/icons/file.png", context),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
  }

Widget optionCards(
String text,
String assetImage,
BuildContext context,
) {
return Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
    color: Colors.grey,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(5),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13),
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: null,
            icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
            fontFamily: 'CeraPro',
            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain state for holding selected Tab.

Your code is updated with Tab bar Feasibility.

Updated Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Card extends StatefulWidget {
  const Card({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Card> createState() => _CardState();
}

class _CardState extends State<Card> {
  String selectedCard = '1';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<dynamic> tabOptionsList = [
      {"id": "1", "text": "A options"},
      {"id": "2", "text": "B options"},
      {"id": "3", "text": "C options"}
    ];

    final selectedTabValue = tabOptionsList
        .where((element) => element['id'] == selectedCard)
        .toList()[0]['text'];

    print(selectedTabValue);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Cards"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                optionCards("A", "assets/icons/recycle.png", context, "1"),
                optionCards("B", "assets/icons/tools.png", context, "2"),
                optionCards("C", "assets/icons/file.png", context, "3"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              selectedTabValue,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget optionCards(
      String text, String assetImage, BuildContext context, String cardId) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedCard = cardId;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: cardId == selectedCard ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: null,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.file_copy),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: 'CeraPro',
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 1),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Only the color is changing but when I click on the options, I want to show different widgets(Like different options). I don't know how to do that.

Comment: can you please explain step by step about your requirement

Comment: if the user clicks on option A: it shows different options below it and vice versa. (like a tab bar). I make widgets on my own. But I don't know how we apply condition.

Comment: can you please share them (option widgets)

Comment: I gave you an example: consider we have to show different screens or container() by tapping on them.

Comment: @UsamaKhalid code updated check it once

Comment: I want to show different screens. not the list.